# What is the difference between the eTag and the last modified in http response?

Tags: http

All the answers I have browsed discuss the eTag vs expires tag. But I still can't get the whole picture about the difference between the 2.

Thank you

Comment: Did you read the specification?

Answer (score 0):

`eTag` has an info of the content.
Someting like `MD5(fileconteny_in_binary)+last_modified`